# Efficiency of sample mean

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, efficiency

Since the variance of the sample mean estimator decreases with $n$
$$
Var(\bar{X}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}
$$
does that mean that it becomes more efficient as the sample size grows?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by efficiency: it you are measuring haw small the likely error is given the sample size then this is not a particularly meaningful question: the sample mean of a larger sample tends to give a smaller error because it is a larger sample, not because the estimator gets more efficient.

Comment: The efficiency of an estimator usually refers to the variance ( or MSE ) of that estimator which is  compared to another estimator when they both use the same $n$. So, as Henry explained, the efficiency of an estimator is not associated with the sample size used.